# Refesh ajax code in a given number of seconds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a code below and I have tried it already and its working.

What I am trying to achieve is to load data using ajax to my data tables.

The code below is working but now I would to refresh every 5 to 10 second checking if there is new data in the database.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#get_categories").DataTable({
        "ajax": {    //create an ajax request to display.php
            "url": "process/get_categories.php",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "action"}
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: if you refresh that frequently you'll probably overload your server, and also you might run into issues sometimes whereby one ajax call is still in progress when the next one is due to start.

Comment: okay i can refresh even after 10 minutes.. but what i want is the logic to the refresh that code. i have tried put setInterval function around the code but then data tables will give an error saying #get_categories can not be reinitialised.. so how can i refresh just the code in between

Comment: Can you show the code with the setInterval() on it in addition to the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already defined an AJAX source for your DataTable you can simply call `reload()` in an interval:

```
var table = $("#get_categories").DataTable({
  // settings...
});

setInterval(function () {
  table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000);
```

However, as @ADyson mentions in the comments, refreshing a data source this often can lead to server load problems, depending on how may concurrent users you have accessing the data. I'd suggest looking in to using WebSockets or Server Sent Events as a more scalable alternative.

Comment: Lovely, elegant solution though!

Comment: A suggestion about live push (websockets etc)... https://socket.io/ (I'm not affiliated, its just a useful system)

Comment: socket.io is brilliant, once you get your head around it!